# Is there a way to set the starting page number in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a reporting system where occasionally there will be multiple JasperReports in a row (e.g. a regular report, and an index report at the end). If the regular report is 21 pages long, then I need the subsequent report to start on page 22.

Is there a simple way to tell a JasperReport what page number to start on? I can do this in a roundabout way, but I feel like I am overlooking something simple. Google and Bing searches have not yielded any answers for me. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: How is the report designed? Are these reports (regular and index) embedded as subreports, in the main report?

Comment: No, just 2 regular standalone reports.

Comment: And are you generating these reports from java code? If so, are you compiling and generating these reports, one after the other? What kind of datasource are you using to generate these reports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no feature to say, "Start on page N."

But it doesn't seem that it would be too roundabout to just add a parameter `$P{FirstPageNumber}`. Then in the field where you would normally use the expression `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}`, you would instead use `$V{PAGE_NUMBER} + $P{FirstPageNumber}`.

Answer (score 0):

use "Page "+ $V{PAGE_NUMBER}.lowestOneBit( 1 )