# Multiple Jasper repports page number handler with key

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Hi fellow stackoverflowers,

I have 2 jasper report. Both started with zero page number. I want my second report to start by first jasper report's total page + 1. I have seen great solutions on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42426312/8557381)  or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8735860/8557381) but it is not what I am looking for. I would like to handle my jasper report like html tag with an id for example and then thanks to this id, get my textField and change the page number value in my java code.

For example my textfield is like:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement  x="520" y="1" width="40" height="48" uuid="5df12c06-9c58-4b26-99c1-02b1d8e86456"/>
    <box>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem This is how I solved it. In your textfileld you need a key.It will be your id like. You should have something like this:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement key="textFieldCurrentPage" x="520" y="1" width="40" height="48" uuid="5df12c06-9c58-4b26-99c1-02b1d8e86456"/>
    <box>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

In your java code you can have something like:

```
// create your second jasper print
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(..., ..., ...);

List<JRPrintPage> listPages = jasperPrint.getPages();
int numberOfPages = listPages.size();
int currentPageIndex = 1;
for (JRPrintPage currentPage : listPages) {
    List listElements = currentPage.getElements();

    for (Object element : listElements) {
        if (element instanceof JRTemplatePrintText) {
            JRTemplatePrintText templatePrintText = (JRTemplatePrintText) element;
            // set currrent page
            if (templatePrintText.getKey() != null
                    && templatePrintText.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("textFieldCurrentPage")) {
                    templatePrintText.setText(String.valueOf(lastPageNumber + currentPageIndex));
            }
        }
    }
    currentPageIndex++;
}
```

I hope that could help you!